tsParticles not rendering particles, options.json load complete, no errors
I'm attempting to use tsParticles with no framework. Trying to use a Polygon Mask with animated particles. It is using the current (at this time) NPM packages, version 3.4.0.
The background loads, and the .svg file loads and there are no console errors. But there are no particles displayed. Do I need to initialize it some how, or are they being rendered off screen some how? Not sure what the issue is here.
I'm using their config files from the npm package: "@tsparticles/configs" Here is my code:


import { tsParticles } from "@tsparticles/engine";
import { loadPolygonMaskPlugin } from "@tsparticles/plugin-polygon-mask";
import { default as configs } from "@tsparticles/configs";

const log = console.log.bind(console);

log(configs.basic);

loadPolygonMaskPlugin(tsParticles);

tsParticles
  .load(
    { id: "tsparticles", options: configs.multiplePolygonMasks }
  )
  .then((container) => {
    log("callback - tsparticles config loaded");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#tsparticles {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>tsParticles Polygon Mask</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tsparticles"></div>
    <div id="print"></div>
</body>
</html>



Here is my package.json file:


{
  "dependencies": {
    "@tsparticles/configs": "^3.4.0",
    "@tsparticles/engine": "^3.4.0",
    "@tsparticles/plugin-polygon-mask": "^3.4.0",
    "vite": "^5.3.1",
    "vite-plugin-mkcert": "^1.17.5"
  }
}



I'm not sure what else to change, this is basically a straight example right out of the box of the tsParticles NPM package.

The problem was that not all of the required modules were imported. Wasn't sure which ones it needed specifically, so I just ran: npm i @tsparticles/all in the terminal.
js code now looks like:


import { loadAll } from "@tsparticles/all";
import { default as configs } from "@tsparticles/configs";

const log = console.log.bind(console);

log(configs);

loadAll(tsParticles);

tsParticles
  .load(
    { id: "tsparticles", options: configs.multiplePolygonMasks }
  )
  .then((container) => {
    log("callback - tsparticles config loaded");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });



And things work now.

SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
